# How to make f.lux change the lighting more smoothly and gradually

Tags: windows-10, f.lux

I'm on windows 10, using f.lux to change the colour on my monitor as the evening arrives.

I was wondering if there is a way to make this happen more gradually. As it is now, 5:30pm arrives and then bam, my monitor has turned completely red. I would much rather a steady and gradual transition that occurs over the course of the entire day.

I've mucked around with all of the settings and can't seem to find what I'm looking for. The "transition speed" setting sounded promising, but ultimately made no difference.

Comment: Please add tag "flux"

Comment: Both the tag & app are called f.lux - flux is what you put on wires to solder them ;)